# How do you know when an input stream has reached the last word in a line?

Tags: c++

I'm reading input from an ifstream in C++. The input comes as a bunch of words separated by tabs, so I'm reading in something like "word1 word2 word3" as stream >> w1 >> w2 >> w3; I need to know when I've reached the final word in the line, so how would I go about that? The number of words is variable, but it should be always even. Also, will the last word contain the \n, or will the \n be the last word?

Comment: Read line-by-line instead, using [`istream::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) or [`<string>`'s free-function `getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

Comment: @vBx When?  You should never test for `eof` until input has failed.  And he's looking for end of line, not end of file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest (and usual) solution is to read lines using
`std::getline`, and then parse the line using
`std::istringstream`:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( std::cin, line ) ) {
    std::istringstream s( line );
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string word;
    while ( s >> word ) {
        words.push_back( word );
    }
    //  ...
}
```

Comment: will the last word contain the \n, or will it be \n?

Comment: @higgs241 No, all whitespace characters, including line feed and carriage return, will be skipped when parsing the tokens from the stream. The last token for every line will contain the last word in that line.

Comment: @higgs241 `std::getline` extracts the `'\n'`, but doesn't put it in the buffer, so it never appears in `s`.  (Of course, if it did, it would be considered as white space, just like a space or tab, and so never appear in a `word`.)

Comment: I see, I guess I was just confused about the extraction of words.

Answer (score 3):

Read from `ifstream` and push it to vector using `algorithm`'s `std::copy` like following:

```
std::ifstream stream("input.txt");
std::vector<std::string> vec;

//replace stream with std::cin for reading from console
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream),
     std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
     std::back_inserter(vec));
```

This needs a EOF for termination. <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> depeding on windows or linux.

As suggested, you can use C++11's initializer list as follows:

```
std::vector<std::string>  vec{std::istream_iterator<std::string>{stream}, 
                              std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}};
```

Comment: Or simply construct the vector using `std::vector<std::string> vec{std::istream_iterator<std::string>{stream},
     std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}}`.

Comment: Except that the PO wants to read words line by line, so he can know how many words are in the line.  This reads the entire file, and looses the very information he wanted to capture.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to `mmap()` the file. After that, you have the entire file in your virtual address space and can examine it at leisure like a big array of characters. Especially for such operations, where you have to go back a few steps, this is the most appropriate approach. As an added bonus, it's also the fastest...

Comment: It's also non-portable, and he doesn't need to back up.  And why should he do the extra parsing, when `istream` will do it for him?

Comment: @JamesKanze It's the POSIX standard. Yes, there are some proprietary systems that don't support sensible standards, but they have similar facilities AFAIK. And I believe there are ways to pass any string in a buffer to a string-stream or similar for parsing, or am I wrong on that one? The subject of the question is trivial enough to just do it yourself without bloating the code in any way. I've recently written a fully blown parser of my own, and having the entire file accessible as one long piece of virtual memory has simplified things a lot. I would have gone mad had I tried to use streams.

Comment: Most modern systems support something similar, and most people who've worked in C++ for any length of time have a class in their toolkit which wraps it in a portable manner.  But it's not a good answer to his problem.  (And I've written more than a few parsers which used `std::istream` on a file open in text mode.  If you design a parser right, there's rarely or never any need to back up.)