# Construct container with initializer list of iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, uniform-initialization

It's possible to construct a vector with an iterator range, like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{std::cin},
                             std::istream_iterator<std::string>{});
```

But I can also compile and run code using C++11 uniform initialization syntax (note the bracers), like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec{std::istream_iterator<std::string>{std::cin},
                             std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}};
```

What's really going on here?

I know that a constructor taking an initializer list *gets priority over other forms of construction*. Shouldn't the compiler resolve to the constructor taking an initializer list containing 2 elements of `std::istream_iterator`? This should be an error as a `std::istream_iterator` can't be converted to the vectors value type `std::string`, right?

Comment: Is this coming from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978410/how-do-you-know-when-an-input-stream-has-reached-the-last-word-in-a-line/17978633#17978633 ? :D

Comment: @P0W YES! :) I've used this syntax many times but it got me wondering when you described it as using C++11 initialization list and not simply uniform initialization bracers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From §13.3.2/1 ([over.match.list])

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized
>   (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list
>   constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of
>   the initializer list as a single argument.
>
> — If no viable
>   initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is
>   performed again, where the candidate functions are all the
>   constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the
>   elements of the initializer list.

In your case the initializer list constructor is deemed non-viable (because `std::istream_iterator<std::string>` is not convertible to `std::string`), and the second condition applies. This results in the constructor taking 2 iterators to be selected.

Comment: And there's the explanation. Thanks! :)