# Assign Static unsigned char* to std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, vector, char, unsigned

I have following in my code:

```
static unsigned char* table;
...
table = something here;
```

Now I have to assign this `table` to variable of type `std::vector<unsigned char>` and I am unable to do so. I am doing:

```
unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*) table;
std::vector<unsigned char>::size_type size = strlen((const char*)buffer);
std::vector<unsigned char>static rawTable(buffer, buffer + size);
for(ByteBuffer::iterator it=rawTable.begin();it!=rawTable.end();++it)
    std::cout << "Raw Table: "<<*it<< std::endl;
```

I am able to compile the code, but no value is there inside rawTable. Please help!
I have verified that variable `table` has value. I appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: What's `ByteBuffer`? `typedef std::vector<unsigned char> ByteBuffer;`? Also, have you checked the value of `size`?

Comment: can you print `table` and `*table` to `cerr`on separate lines before printing the vector?

Comment: What is the value of `size`? Doesn't the constructor of `vector` take `(buffer, size)` instead?

Comment: You say you've verified that `table` has values, but did you check that *before* this code is executed?  Are you sure that this code isn't be executed before `table` is initialized?

Comment: @Lump: There's a vector constructor which takes a pair of iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strlen` gives you the length of a string, not the size of an arbitrary memory region.  If your `table` has a `'\0'` anywhere inside, `strlen` will find it and stop counting.

Also, by making `rawTable` a `static` variable, it will not update its value if `buffer` or `size` ever change.  `static` variables are constructed only once.

Also, if this is supposed to be a table of numeric data, you should cast to a numeric non-character type.  Otherwise `cout` may interpret it as ASCII codes.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just used sizeof instead of strlen and removed the static from rawTable. Printing rawTable still does not show any value. Any suggestion?

Comment: @user2962058: `sizeof` has absolutely no chance of working here, it will give you the size of a pointer, not the memory pointed to.  Do you have no way of knowing what the size should be?

Comment: From the code I have, data = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 65536); and this data is being returned as table/buffer. Now if the size if 65536, how should I make the change?

Comment: @user2962058: In that case you could just use `size = 65536` in your code, replacing the `strlen` call.

Answer (score 2):

You have a pointer of type `unsigned char*` pointing to an array.

Then you want to push every element of the array into a `std::vector<unsigned char>`, right?

If so, the key is to know the *size* of the array. You need to know the size beforehand. There's no way to determine the size of the array in the general case with some keyword or function if all that is visible to you is a pointer of type `unsigned char*`. You need to pass that information along with the pointer somehow.

In the case when the pointer of type `unsigned char*` points to an array of characters which is *null-terminated* (e.g. `{'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'}`), then you can use the C-string function `strlen` to count the number of characters in the array using only the pointer. However if the array is not null-terminated this will result in *undefined behaviour*.

When you have the `size` it's a simple matter to populate the `std::vector` with the arrays elements:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> v(arr, arr + size); // arr = pointer to array.
```

This is why you should use the containers in the standard library instead of raw arrays, as these containers internally keep track of the size and you can always access it with the `size()` function.

For constant size arrays use `std::array`. Example:

```
std::array<unsigned char, 3> arr{'f', 'o', 'o'}; // arr.size() == 3
// Print its contents.
for (auto c : arr) {
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Uniform initializer syntax may do the wrong thing here.  Parentheses, not braces, are needed, because you are not supplying a list of items.  `vector` supports initializer lists, but that's not what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @BenVoigt It compiled and ran fine when I tried it with uniform intializer syntax. But you may be right in this case. In the general case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979857/construct-container-with-initializer-list-of-iterators

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem I'm referring to.  It's better not to get in the habit of using list-initialization syntax with vector when you aren't supplying a list of elements, because some vector types actually would treat it as a list of elements.